# How to change email in Facebook account which is already in use with other account

Tags: facebook, facebook-account

Have a Facebook account for several years. Have a new email address and never changed it. On my phone I forgot my password and I opened a new Facebook account with my new email. Here's the problem, I went back on my computer and my old Facebook was still signed on so I tried to change the email but says The email is already on the other Facebook and I can't remember my password on the new Facebook.

When I try to change my password on my old Facebook the code required to change it goes to my old email which I can not get in to get the code. What can I do to have my new email into my old Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your new email id is already in use with your new Facebook account. That is the reason when you are trying to change email id in old Facebook account, it is showing error.

[You cannot use one email id for more than one account.](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10200858261393762)

If you want use your new email id with old Facebook account, then first free-up the new email id, means it should not be associated with any Facebook account.

To free-up you new email id, you first [reset the password](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144?helpref=topq) for your new Facebook account, then change the email id of new Facebook account to free-up new email id immediately or you can delete your Facebook account permanently, after 14 days of deletion your new email id will be free and you can use this with your old Facebook account.

It's better to delete your second Facebook account because It's against the [Facebook Community Standards](https://www.facebook.com/communitystandards/) to maintain more than one personal account.